# How to obtain all related objects in the second level of one-to-many relationship hierarchy?

Tags: django, orm

Let's say I have three models bound in one-to-many relationship like this:

```
class Highest(Model):
    pass


class Medium(Model):
    higher = ForeignKey(Highest, on_delete=CASCADE)


class Lowest(Model):
    higher = ForeignKey(Medium, on_delete_CASCADE)
```

Now if I have an instance of `Highest` called `highest` I can easily obtain all related `Medium` objects this way: `highest.medium_set.all()`

And if I have an instance of `Medium` called `medium` I can easily obtain all related `Lowest` objects this way: `medium.lowest_set.all()`

But how do I obtain all `Lowest` objects that are related to any `Medium` object that is related to a particular `Highest` object?

This doesn't work: `highest.medium_set.lowest_set.all()`

I can always do this: `Lowest.objects.filter(higher__higher=highest).distinct().all()`

But is this the only way? Or can I do it more straightforward? That is, by obtaining all related `Lowest` objects from a `Highest` object rather than filtering through all `Lowest` objects?

Comment: That *is* the most straightforward way. Simply speaking, you should start from the model you want to get, ie Lowest.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to do `highest.medium_set.lowest_set.all()`, you are trying to invoke a queryset method on a queryset itself. This will not work as it is unknown which Medium instance you would like to get all related Lowest objects for.

This should be fine:

```
Lowest.objects.filter(higher__higher=highest)
```